# upgrading to Ubuntu Studio from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have Installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Inkscape and gimp.
I want to know if there is any special advantage of installing ubuntu studio?
By profession I am an artist but also do programing (Graphics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the low latency kernel for one. It comes preloaded with a lot of programs for artists. And then the neat xfse desktop. You will still use Ububtu Software Center for programs or synaptic like usual, but the sound dosn't st studder when under heavy load.
So give it a try, you might like it, like some of us.

Comment: ThanQ Ken.'<Well the low latency kernel for one>' which means there is nothing like "upgrading" my current Trusty to Studio.... as i was imagining, it is just another os (offshoot) altogether :) ie: i will have to download the whole iso.

Comment: Yes I do not think there is any easy way to change the kernen, while keeping all of the integration intact - and it would be a hell of a job - currently beyond my capabilities! But who knows what we will learn in the upcoming time here. Best of luck.